# interpreting eigenvectors/values of linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, intuition

I have two related questions:

1. If I have a system of linear equations, written in matrix form:

   $Ax = b$

   then this system has a non-trivial solution only if $det(A) \neq 0$. but what is the significance of the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of A for finding the solutions?
2. Related, if I have a system of homogeneous ordinary differential equations:

   $x' = Ax$

   then what is the interpretation of eigenvalues/eigenvectors of A in finding the solutions of this system of equations?

pointers to explanations or concise explanations to this would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering eigenvectors this should imply quadratic matrices.

Solving $Ax=b$ then means $x=A^{-1}b$.
If we have a base of eigenvectors, $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvectors, we have
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{diag}{diag}
b = A x = \diag(\lambda_1, \dotsc, \lambda_n) x 
$$
where $diag$ is a diagonal matrix, and the invertation simplifies to
$$
x = \diag(\lambda_1^{-1},\dotsc,\lambda_n^{-1}) b
$$

For the linear ODE system, we have the solution
$$
x(t) = e^{tA} x(0)
$$
Here the matrix exponential simplifies to
$$
e^{tA} = \diag(e^{\lambda_1 t}, \dotsc, e^{\lambda_n t})
$$

Comment: can you give more intuition what the eigenvectors/eigenvalues mean for the matrix *A* in relation to the solution space of system of linear equations?

Comment: To me the key idea here seems that from a special viewpoint a matrix can look simpler and still represents the same linear transformation. That viewpoint is the basis of eigenvectors among all the possible basis choices and the simplification is that $A$ turns into a diagonal matrix  (which has only up to $n$ non-zero elements, compared to the up to $n^2$ otherwise). Do you miss something?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a base of eigenvectors and use it as your frame of reference, you will form equivalent problems were all variables are decoupled.

Both problems now are super simple to solve, and each variable can be solved independently. What makes the original problems hard is the coupling.

It is worth mentioning that in some cases your eigenvectors will not form a base.